# How do I disable payment method in check out?

Tags: attributes, event-observer, payment-methods

i want to do the following thing in checkout. When I have a product in checkout which has its attribute code (**card_only**) selected to "**Da**" then i want to disable a shipping method in checkout.

I created my module with an observer:

```
<?php

class Netlogiqpayment_Paymenttype_Model_Observer{

    public function paymenttype2(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){


        $payments = Mage::getSingleton('payment/config')->getActiveMethods();
        // $payment = $order->getPayment();


        $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
        $shippingMethod = $cart->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();
        $products_id_array = array(); $i = 0;
        foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
            //$productName = $item->getProduct()->getName()."<br>"; 
           //$productPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
            $products_id_array[$i] = $item->getProduct()->getId();
            $i++;
        }
        $c = 0; $attribute_values = array();
        for ($i=0; $i < count($products_id_array); $i++) { 
            $productId = $products_id_array[$i];
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
            $attributes = $product->getAttributes();
            foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {   
                $attributeCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
                if ($attributeCode == 'card_only') {
                    $attribute_values[$c] =  $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
                    $c++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (in_array("Da", $attribute_values)){
             //disable shipping method with card
        }else{
            // enable all shipping method
        }


}
```

}

and this is my config.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Netlogiqpayment_paymenttype>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Netlogiqpayment_paymenttype>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
            <controller_action_postdispatch_gomage_checkout_onepage_index>
                <observers>
                    <paymenttypetest>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>paymenttype/observer</class>
                        <method>paymenttype2</method>
                    </paymenttypetest>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_postdispatch_gomage_checkout_onepage_index>
        </events>
        <models>
            <paymenttype>
                <class>Netlogiqpayment_Paymenttype_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>paymenttype_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </paymenttype>
        </models>
       <!--  <sales>
            <quote>
                <item>
                    <paymenttype/>
                </item>
            </quote>
        </sales> -->
    </global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using this event

```
    Mage::dispatchEvent('payment_method_is_active', array(
        'result'          => $checkResult,
        'method_instance' => $this,
        'quote'           => $quote,
    ));

    //...
    return $checkResult->isAvailable;
```

and then just set the isAvailable accordingly in your observer class based on your requirements.

Comment: ok but who is the variable $checkout , $this and $quote ? can you post a full answer please ? thx a lot !

Comment: The event is dispatched in /app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Abstract.php so $this will be your payment method class instance that inherits from this class.

Comment: sorry I just don't get it. Can you update your post with my code and your code ? to be more understandable ? thx

Comment: Sorry if you want a full solution you might have to hire someone to do the work for you. When I am volunteering my time I will only give you a general direction for a solution. Best of luck.

Comment: thx man i really appreciate it